# Erlang cannot run in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

Trying to run simple erlang file in intellij.

```
-module('Tutorial').

%% API
-export([helloWorld/0]).

helloWorld() -> io:write("Hello World").
```

But when I try to run I always get

```
init terminating in do_boot ()

{"init terminating in do_boot",{{unbound_var,'Tutorial'},[{erl_eval,exprs,2,[]}]}}
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Im using erlang 8.3 and a intellij plugin for erlang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
-module('tutorial').
```

in a file called: "tutorial.erl". The expression: "Tutorial" is interpreted as a variable (because the first letter is capitalized). When the runtime encounters this variable, it tries to evaulate it, but since it is not defined, you get the error.

Comment: Oh i see... variables are with capital letter. Need to learn erlang naming convention :D. Ty.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of- atoms (which module names are) can be capitalized if surrounded by single quotes, as seen here. I'm not sure how you're running the code, but the following illustrates (the code is in Foo.erl).

```
-module('Foo').

-export([bar/0]).

bar() ->
  io:format("foobar~n").
```

And then

```
1> c("Foo.erl").
{ok,'Foo'}
2> 'Foo':bar().
foobar
ok
3>
```

Comment: i was running it with intelliJ. I can setup runconfig for it adn when i press run it should run it but instead i got this error, additionally i tryed on command line, still got the error. So changing Tutorial -> tutorial worked for me.

Comment: I think internally, intelli-j uses an erlang-shell command to compile modules like: `c(Foo)` where `Foo` is not the file-name quoted, but the module-name, without quotes. I ran into exactly the same problems.